# Calculating sum of input type generated using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have these input fields with same id, name. These inputs are generated using the ajax code as per the user choices. I want to do the sum of theses input fields(p_amount) in total_amount field using jquery.

```
<input type="text" id="p_amount" name="p_amount[]" placeholder="Enter Amount ">
<input type="text" id="p_amount" name="p_amount[]" placeholder="Enter Amount ">

<input type="text" id="p_amount" name="p_amount[]" placeholder="Enter Amount ">
<input type="text" id="p_amount" name="p_amount[]" placeholder="Enter Amount ">
<input type="text" id="p_amount" name="p_amount[]" placeholder="Enter Amount ">

<input type="text" id="total_amount" name="total_amount"  value="" placeholder="Total Amount">
```

I am using following js code but it only return the sum of digits entered in first text field. and i want sum of all the id's with p_amount. Please help me here.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#total_amount').click(function() {
    var p_amount=$("#p_amount").val();
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < p_amount.length; i++) {
        total += p_amount[i] << 0;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You know that you have a syntax error in your code? You should add `});` before the `</script>`

Comment: You can't have two elements with the same id. That's as error and can create unexpected behaviour especially on selectors. Use `class` instead

Comment: ID has to be unique, that's why you only receive the first value, use a different selector

Comment: try `$('input[name="p_amount[]"]')` as the selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
var total=0;
$('#total_amount').click(function() {
    $("input[name='p_amount[]'").each(function(){
        total+=parseInt($(this).val());
    });
});
alert(total);
```

Comment: thanks, it worked just i had to remove syntax error 
replaced 
 $("input[name='p_amount[]'").each(function()
with
$('input[name="p_amount[]"]').each(function()

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `id`s of the fields you use must be distinct. You should use `class` attributes for annotating multiple elements.

Then you can get these with JQuery and iterate through them with .each().

You can find more information and examples here:
[JQuery .each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)